# SQL - define keys to table

Tags: sql-server, database-design

Is there any considerations to define **keys** for table that has lot of records already and most of operation that are operated on it are **Insert** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key definition ultimately comes down to how you can uniquely and efficiently identify any specific row in a table.  If a business key value fulfills that requirement, then it is a suitable candidate.  An ideal key is also skinny.  A GUID is horrible for this (IMHO) because it is far larger than it needs to be.

If insert performance is the most important priority and a suitable business key is not available, you can use an integer based identity key.  If you expect more than 2.1 billion records within a few years, use bigint (9 quintillion records) instead.

Keep in mind that every index you make on the table will always include the PK.  Having a skinny PK can make your indexes more efficient, using less storage, memory and CPU.

Insert speed is affected by the clustered index sort order as well as the number and sort order of all non-clustered indexes on the table.  Column-store indexes are not sorted and have minimal overhead on inserts.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a PK that store ID-number is more heavy then auto increases number, therefore when you define key keep in mind that it bather to create another column of PK for auto increases number.